# Problems reading data from Binary store in /tmp/gradle7963227675482339513.bin (exist: true)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-release-plugin

Gradle refresh failed error while trying to import an old project into the android studio.
How can this be resolved? Thanks.

> Error:Problems reading data from Binary store in /tmp/gradle7963227675482339513.bin (exist: true)

Comment: hi do you find solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I just cleaned project and re-ran.Issue resolved